# Errors CDATA validation W3C XHTML

Tags: xhtml, cdata, w3c-validation

I am getting the following error from w3c validation
which corresponds to this code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
hs.gr = '/tx/';
.
.
.
uss: false});
// ]]&gt;</script>
```

What is the problem?
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `&gt;` entity reference with a literal `>`.

```
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
hs.gr = '/tx/';
.
.
.
uss: false});
// ]]></script>
    </body>
```